# Investigating if two strains of a virus are more likely than chance to occur together in a person

Tags: logistic-regression, pairwise

I am trying to explore if among 13 genotypes of a virus, any 2 are more likely to occur together in pairs in a person who can have multiple infections. my datastructure for this exploration is by visit, i.e a person can have multiple rows, each row corresponding to a visit in my study. I have a column for each genotype, indicating whether the person was positive or negative for that genotype (0 or 1) at a particular visit/row.

I have tried a clustered logistic regression, where i run each genotype as a dependent variable, with all remaining 12 genotypes as independent variables, to see the pairwise odds ratios..i cluster by participant ID to adjust standard errors as visits are clustered by people. Given that i have 13 genotypes and pairs of two, 13C2~ tells me that i will be making 78 pairwise comparisons/ 78 walds tests. so i will correct for multiple hypothesis testing by dividing 0.05 by 78 for significance. however i am wondering if there is other biases that i am not accounting for? or if there are better ways of going about exploring this question.